# WP7 How to target two controls at the same time with a Storyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, storyboard

I can't seem to find a way to target two controls at the same time with my Storyboard. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storyboard itself doesn't target controls, the individual animations does. Just use a different `TargetName` for your animations.

Comment: Hi Claus. I don't quite follow what you mean by "Just use a different TargetName". Are you saying I should just change the TargetName property of the animation? But that will not animate the originally targeted control. Can you kindly elaborate please?

Comment: No, I'm saying you need **one** animation **per** control. Inside the same storyboard of course.